# Create a Pull Request on GitHub when both branches match

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am using GitHub with my team. I have a new branch (called new) based on the master branch and nothing has been committed to new, so both new and master are still matching branches in terms of their being no diff. I would like a PR between this new branch and the master to exist in Github as a place for our team to have a discussion before committing anything to the new branch. When I select "New pull request" in GitHub, the first page, I'm presented with a "Comparing Changes" page where "There isn’t anything to compare. master and new are identical." and I cannot seem to create the PR.

On GitHub, is there a way I can force a PR to be created between matching branches?

Alternately, are there any conventional approaches to creating some inconsequential diff that will allow me to create a PR between two branches that would otherwise match?

Comment: Use an issue to start a discussion and then later reference the issue in the PR after there are commits to diff.

Comment: Thanks @doelleri I will try to start to use issues to track the conversations that precede a PR. My situation is that our CI pipeline configuration is PR based, listening for new PRs to master in our GitHub repo, and rebuilding in the Dev environment on each commit. I'd like to start the pipeline in my feature build with a known stable build. The only build I know to be stable is master; so I'd like to start there to build certain artifacts in Dev which will persist until I merge the PR (PVCs for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [issue](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-issues) to start a discussion and then later [reference that issue](https://help.github.com/en/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords#about-issue-references) in a pull request after work has been done and there are commits to diff to your base branch.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion based on WHAT I THINK you're trying to do.

Why not create a random branch, say `temp` and commit everything and have discussions there before pushing to master.

Comment: I should have used arbitrary branch labels instead of mentioning `master` to avoid confusion.


Consider matching branches `a` and `b`. I want to create a PR from `b` to `a`. I don't want to have to commit any changes to branch `b` first.